# How to debug chained method calls?

Tags: c#

...using .net 4.0

by chained method calls I mean

```
public bool CallA(){
  return CallB().HasAccess;
}

public User CallB(){
  return new User{ HasAccess = true};
}
```

Is there a way to debug in CallA to see what is returned from CallB() .  I generally return calls into an object, check for null, etc, but this is existing code that I don't want to alter just so I can debug a little easier.

Comment: Why don't you want to alter just so you can debug easier?

Comment: So, you'd like to add debug code without adding code?

Comment: why won't the immediate window work... Just put the breakpoint in CallB or breakpoint CallA and run the CallB from the immediate window

Answer (score 3):

You could put a breakpoint on `return CallB().HasAccess` and add a quickwatch on `CallB()` to see what returns.

Comment: Note that this can cause side-effects.

Comment: The breakpoint is activated before the line is executed. You need to save the temp result and break

Comment: @IAbstract You're calling CallB() again

Comment: @Tim S: Agreed about that in some situations this could have undesired side-effects (normally not but depends on the internal logic) . Although probably make no sense his request, just wanted to provide the only option I can think of debugging that without changing any line of code.

Comment: I have done the QuickWatch, but as already mentioned, that can sometimes have side effects.  But thanks for actually answering

Answer (score 2):

```
public bool CallA()
{
    User ret = CallB();
    // breakpoint on this next line
    return ret.HasAccess;
}
```

Comment: @Cole +1 for at least giving an answer